# Error while installing .NET framework 3.5

Tags: .net

The .NET Framework 3.5 installation fails for me. Right after the 
"Downloading components" stage, it sits for a few seconds on:

> Setup has finished downloading components, you can now disconnect from the 
>   Internet

Then it starts to roll back. I'm using Windows XP SP2. A glance 
in the log files shows that it seems related to [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) error code 1603.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Windows Installer - here is a link to the [4.5 download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5a58b56f-60b6-4412-95b9-54d056d6f9f4).

Comment: i think this shouldn't be the reason. if your windows installer is too old the setup of .net will tell this to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a more detailed error in one of the locations mentioned in blog post *[Where to find .NET Framework 2.0 SP1, 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP1, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 and 3.5 SP1 setup log files](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/04/30/8445569.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename c:\windows\system32\spupdsvc.exe to something else and retry the .NET Framework 3.5 installation. 
If you using a batch file you can use:
"REN c:\windows\system32\spupdsvc.exe spupdsvc2.exe"